# who command: What does the comment header exactly represent?

Tags: command-line, users, who

When either the `who -a -H` or `who -u -H` commands are executed - and having many users logged through `tty` and `ssh` - the command works as expected.

I did realise the `COMMENT` header appears **but** always empty.

**Question**

- What does the *comment* header **exactly** represent?

**Extra Questions**

- From where should appear the data for the `comment` header?
- Where and how to put a comment to see it later there? - it only if is possible or viable through a manual process

Comment: this may help ... https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-who-command-examples-syntax-usage/

Comment: I read that tutorial, and yes, in many outputs the "comment" header has values, but from where come from? And why there appears and in my case not - BTW Ubuntu is running through VirtualBox

Comment: @ManuelJordan Ubuntu shows the "hostname" data from `/var/log/wtmp` in the comment field.  This is the same data that is hidden from the output of `last` if you use `last` with `-R`. It is unclear whether you want a general answer to this question (there is not one as the data may come from any source), or whether you want an answer related to a specific Unix system.  On OpenBSD, the column is called `FROM` instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda I assumed the `who` command works in the same way for all the Linux environments. - Question edited to avoid confusions. Now including extra questions

Comment: It's FOSS (Free Open Source Software). Look at the C source. `apt source $(dpkg -S $( type -p who) | cut -c: -f1 )`

Comment: In `coreutils`, the `COMMENT` is the host, see the implementation: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/e087525091b8f0a15eb2354f71032597d5271599/src/who.c#L434